# How to use !default in a SASS mixin?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have this SASS mixin:

```
@mixin micro-clearfix
    &:after,
    &:before
        content: ""
        display: table
    &:after
        clear: both
    * html &
        height: 1% !default
    *+html &
        min-height: 1% !default
```

Unfortunately, it does not compile, unless I remove `!default` which would be the point of having this mixin.

The error message I'm getting is:

```
Invalid CSS after "1% ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "!default")
```

What I'd like to achieve is that if `height` (or `min-height`) has already been defined for the selector then the mixin should use that value, otherwise it should define this property as 1%.

I don't wish to use `zoom` since that's not a valid property and I like to keep my CSS clean.

Am I using `!default` the wrong way?

I have Compass 0.12.1 and SASS 3.1.10.

Comment: `!default` is used with Sass variable declarations, not CSS properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how I've done it finally:

```
@mixin micro-clearfix
    $minHeight: 1% !default
    &:after,
    &:before
        content: ""
        display: table
    &:after
        clear: both
    * html &
        height: $minHeight
    *+html &
        min-height: $minHeight
```

Comment: Why not pass in `$minHeight` to your mixin and set the default like `@mixin micro-clearfix($minHeight: 1%)`?

Answer (score 14):

`!default` is intended to use only when declaring variables: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_defaults_

What you are trying to do should be done with [CSS `!important` declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules), which should be used in the rule outside the mixin (the one you want to prevail). Anyway, using `!important` usually it's not a good practice. Maybe you could rely on cascade or specificity.

Comment: Thank you for the response but as you have mentioned using `!important` is generally unadvisable, so I cannot accept your answer, besides I have found a solution myself.